# WordPress - Reserved form field names?

Tags: php, forms, plugins, wordpress

I have installed a simple PayPal Cart plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-ultra-simple-paypal-shopping-cart/

Installed just fine. However, when updating a quantity or anything that involves the posting of a form, WordPress returns a 404 error page.

Now, when investigating, I noticed someone mentioned that WordPress has some reserved words for form field names internally.

( http://wordpress.org/support/topic/404-pops-after-custom-form-submission-by-post )

I followed this trail and altered the name fields with Firebug on the fly and post the form.

Everything was post to the current page and it stayed on the same page (as expected) instead of the 404. So it seems that this *IS* indeed a WordPress issue.

Is there any way I can add exceptions to certain names in WordPress as a setting of some sort? Or if anyone knows a work-around for this plugin, I'd much appreciate it.

Many thanks for your input.
Michael.

**EDIT:**

Someone has also had this problem. See this thread...

http://www.ultra-prod.com/developpement-support/wp-ultra-simple-paypal-shopping-cart-group3/bugs-errors-help-forum8/404-error-thread76/

Any idea on a solution? I can't simply rename my post type. This is for a website that's already in production and has hundreds of products.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: There seem to be plenty of people using this plugin successfully - no obvious problems on http://www.ultra-prod.com/developpement-support/wp-ultra-simple-paypal-shopping-cart-group3.0/ - are you on the latest versions of WP and the plugin?

Comment: Yes, latest WP and latest WP_Cart plugin. I read somewhere that using a custom post type of "product" conflicts with something, so I'm going to change my custom post type and see what happens.

Comment: Hi, there's a conflict, but I can't think of a solution other than renaming the post type...but I can't do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Just did a quick search, and there appear to be only two lines in `wp_ultra_simple_shopping_cart.php` where form fields are given the `name="product"` attribute (lines 479 & 571). Try changing them. No guarantees, however, as I haven't installed the plugin, but it's worth a try. And it'll break again if and when you upgrade the plugin.

Comment: Cheers. I ended up modifying the entire reference to "product". Beware though...I had to also make changes to POST variables and variable names. Seems to work though. It's a pretty obvious over-sight on the plugin authors part. Should always prefix these with something unique.

Comment: Don't name your inputs like `name=name` because when you post them it's conflicting with WP_Query's name attribute in WP page lifecycle . So when you send a post data like `name=test` , WP_Query looking for a post which name (slug) is **test**.